# How do I get video to load faster on a web page?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video

I am beginning to add more video to web pages, but being new to the task I am trying to find the right balance between quality and load time.

I added two videos to [this page](http://hobblecreek.us/blog/entry/tiny-camera-big-views) (scroll down just past the red car) and you can see the videos. The first one is 720p but takes forever to load.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<video autoplay="" class="video" loop="" muted="">
  <source src="/assets/video/Newport-beach-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
  Your browser does not support video.
</video>
```

I have researched html 5 and video but I would really like to find out what the optimal encoding for web-based video is and how to optimize loading on web pages.

Comment: Are you serving the videos over http, right there on your webserver?

Comment: Yes. These videos are on the same server. Thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: Well, for starters, you are hosting multiple sites on this server. That tells me it does not have the juice you will need, plus you may not have the appropriate bandwidth from your server to reliably stream for everyone. You are looking for high high res portfolio quality videos, not youtube quality (or i imagine you would use youtube). Simple encoding optimization is not going to get you there. You are going to want to look into some streaming video hosting. There are very affordable solutions (often cheaper than your regular hosting), even a CDN would do you better.

Comment: I only have a couple of sites hosted and they are not high traffic, but the bandwidth is obviously not enough to deliver the video. I would be happy with YouTube quality, but would rather go with the clean look without all the controls, especially for full-width background videos. Any other guidance you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: You could look at reskinning the YouTube Player. There are a few ways out there, including some services like https://www.reembed.com/ Is that worth an answer? Haha.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Madness says above, hosting videos is a specialised area and the balance of quality vs speed is key as you have noted.

It is common to use separate web servers for different type of content on websites, typically static vs dynamic content, but also for specialised content like video.

Some suggestions in rough order of complexity/expense for your case:

- host the videos on amazon S3, using their CDN Cloudfront to help speed up delivery (example discussed in blog here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/using-amazon-cloudfront-for-video-streaming/)
- Host the video on a specialised streaming video hosting site such as Brightcove, Wistia etc. (example guidelines: http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/quick-video-publishing)
- Set up your own streaming server to host your videos (example overveiw: http://www.wowza.com/uploads/wowza4/documents/WowzaStreamingEngine-Product-Overview_final.pdf)

It is worth understanding how a typical streaimg server balances quality and speed to help you decide the best approach: they use a technique called adaptive bit rate streaming.

This essentially creates multiple bit rate versions of your video and then breaks them up into equal chunks (equal from a 'time' point of view, not size). The client then can request the bit rate for the next chunk it requires from the most appropriate bit rate for the current network conditions - if the network is bad at the moment it will get a low bit rate chunk and if it is good a high bit rate chunk.

Typically, videos start either at a low bit rate or a medium bit rate to allow quick start.

You can see this in action on YouTube if you look at the stats while playing back a HTML5 video.

Using one of the hosting services will hide all this complexity from you, hence their popularity...

Comment: Hi Mick, This is exactly the kind of answer that I needed. Thank you for taking the time to provide it in such useful detail.