# How to make an element be the first to display on my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a video file(.mp4) to be the first thing that displays on my webpage before anything else displays. This is because the video file seems to be the last to display, and I need it to be the very first element to be displayed.

```
.showcase
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #111;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```
<section class="showcase">
    <video controlsList="nodownload" src="https://btcscriptsmaker.com/earnfreebitcoin.mp4" muted loop autoplay>
    </video>
</section>
```

Comment: First thing that displays in order of time? First thing that displays in order of vertical position? First thing that displays in order of depth?

Comment: In order of time

Comment: put it as far up in the HTML as possible. the first things to load are in the `<head>` tag, the first things to render are higher up inside the `<body>` tag. If you place your video as the first item inside of the `<body>` tag, your video will be the very first thing to render in order of time.

Comment: @maraaaaaaaa Thanks tho. Although since it's a mp4 file it may take longer to load up, as I've researched. Maybe I need a best site that can convert mp4 file to gif, reducing the size drastically but not the quality, if anything of such exists. Then I think my problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is on the loading of the video the answare is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887761/how-do-i-get-video-to-load-faster-on-a-web-page)

If the problem is that the video is under other elements you can use the css tag z-index: 6. With it the video will be over other elementes.

If the problem is the layout, you can create a div, put int the video, use the tag position: absolute and set height: 100vh and width: 100%

If the problem is something else please give more infos.

Comment: Thank you brother, the problem is the loading of the video, the file is about 29mb. I actually need it as a background display at the top most of my page, the first thing that should show, up in my page. So I suggest if I could convert the mp4 file to gif, reducing the file size drastically but without distorting/reducing the quality it. Because it's really cool and would not want it blurry or distorted. I do hope you understand what I'm saying. Please your suggestion is vital, thanks

Comment: Seems uploading video on AWS Amazon is paid, as seen in the link you sent me, and other servers as well - ("amazon S3, using their CDN Cloudfront")